# Convert any PDF to an ebook?

Tags: pdf, ebook

What is the most **reliable** way to convert **any** text-containing PDF to a **reflowable** format **without errors**?
Including OCR'd scans?

Any platforms welcome.

Comment: It won't be **reliable**, because converting text to pdf is a lossy operation. Especially if you have scans and need OCR.

Comment: converting text to pdf is not a lossy operation unless you explicitly bake that text as raster image. PDF is not only for images. It can, and most do, have text content that can be perfectly extractable for manipulation by other tools.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at calibre.  Available here: http://calibre-ebook.com/

Comment: Calibre supports exporting PDF to a reflowable format?  That's news to me, do you have details?

Comment: Calibre lists PDF as an input format, and as far as I know any input format can be converted to any of the supported output formats. PDF is also listed as an output format. I've seen numerous references to Calibre's reflow results not being perfect, which I assume means it works to some degree. For example, http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=118173. Of course PDF is not a preferred format in any case (I use .lit since I mostly use my Pocket PC as an e-reader, but .epub and .mobi work quite well too.)